# How to scan 1D barcode in device horizontal state when orientation is locked using budiyev scanning library

Tags: java, android, kotlin, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am developing a scanning application, where I scan and generate Qr code and barcode everything works fine but when it comes to scanning 1D barcode horizontally when mobile orientation is locked (configuration changes don't take place) the scanner doesn't scan the 1D barcode but can scan Qr code in both vertical and horizontal state (I am not using portrait and landscape as these are correct terms because I need to scan the barcode while the user holds mobile horizontally when device orientation is locked).

**The library I am using:**

```
 implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
 implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
 implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'
```

**My XML:**

```
<com.budiyev.android.codescanner.CodeScannerView
    android:id="@+id/scanner_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/scanner_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/scanner_view_height"
    app:flashButtonVisible="false"
    app:autoFocusButtonVisible="false"
    app:frameAspectRatioWidth="0.9"
    app:frameAspectRatioHeight="0.9"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null"
    app:frameCornersSize="0dp"
    app:maskColor="@color/white"
    />
```

**My Code:**

```
private var mCodeScanner: CodeScanner? = null
 val scannerView: CodeScannerView = view.findViewById(R.id.scanner_view)
     mCodeScanner = CodeScanner(activity!!, scannerView)

     mCodeScanner!!.decodeCallback = DecodeCallback { result ->
                    activity.runOnUiThread {
                        //Toast.makeText(activity, "" + result.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        // scannedTV.setText(result.getText());
                        val intent = Intent(activity, ScanResultActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("loadResult", result.text)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
```

**Library Classes:**
[Library Class for Scanning Code](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner/blob/master/src/main/java/com/budiyev/android/codescanner/CodeScanner.java)

[Library Class for Scanner View](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner/blob/master/src/main/java/com/budiyev/android/codescanner/CodeScannerView.java)

You can also find the rest library classes and interface there. Do I need to modify the library if so I have imported the library as a module but I don't understand the code the right way. I have also mentioned the issue on GitHub in the library issue section but no response yet
any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: The repository which you've linked has an [issues](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner/issues) section... and ZXing has no problem to do that. Modern imagers have no issue with the orientation either - a camera image is not alike the age-old 1D laser scanners.

Comment: Is there any way to update that repo and make it able to scan barcodes horizontally...

Comment: Just fork it and fix it ...but why bother, when ZXing doesn't have this problem??

Comment: I need camera rotate, flash and zooming features. I think zxing doesn't provide all these features by default or does it Sir?

Comment: Complaining about abandoned GitHub repositories and requesting libraries is generally considered as off-topic on here.... just open `build.gradle`, add CameraX, add ZXing, then learn how to program.